# How to pin multiple SliverAppBars to the top from different scroll views

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is the case, the first sliverAppBar pins to the top correctly when scrolling. Within customScrollView are two tabs that have its' own scroll view. Inside the first tab, is another sliverAppBar that is supposed to pin under the first one. However, it slides beneath the first sliverAppBar. Now since our complex view does not allow only one customScrollView to fix the problem, is there any other way?

See image here (Notice how first AppBar overlaps the second AppBar)

[image]

**Desired Effect Before Scroll**

[image]

**Desired Effect After Scroll**

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}
 
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> _tabs = ['Tab 1', 'Tab 2'];
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: _tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(
                title: const Text('1st App Bar'),
                pinned: true,
                forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: _tabs.map((String name) => Tab(text: name)).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
                      itemExtent: 48.0,
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item $index'),
                          );
                        },
                        childCount: 3,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SliverAppBar(
                    toolbarHeight: 150,
                    pinned: true,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                    title: Text('2nd App Bar'),
                  ),
                  SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
                      itemExtent: 48.0,
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text('Item $index'),
                          );
                        },
                        childCount: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Placeholder(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: on 1st Tab there will be another AppBar, and second tab will only use 1st appBar am i right?

Comment: in this case, i think there will a conflict of scroll, to handle this we need to switch two scrollControlloers i think.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh any idea or example on how to make that work?

Comment: im not sure about passing the same controller. else we have to check if child ScrollController offset is 0, then enable parent Scrollcontroller. and switch between them in this manner.

Comment: Could you @YeasinSheikh provide an example, not sure how to approach the suggestion?

Comment: According to this UI, i may use PinnedHeader on `multiSliver` from `sliver_tools` .

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh, tried multiSliver  it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Scaffold` to hold 1st `appBar`. And inside `tab` we can make 2nd appBar as pinned. Let me know if you wish any changes.

**Output**

[image]

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static const List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'Tab1'),
    Tab(text: 'Tab2'),
  ];

  late TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: myTabs.length, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Appbar 1"),
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                title: Text("AppBar 2"),
                pinned: true,
              ),
              SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
                  itemExtent: 48.0,
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('Item $index'),
                      );
                    },
                    childCount: 213,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work but it will mitigate the sliverAppBar functionality when expanding as slivers do.

Comment: about the 1st AppBar?

Comment: Right, the first 1st AppBar

Comment: let me check if i can migrate that one sliver too.

Comment: Thanks, thats where we are quite stuck.. :/

Comment: there are some errors i'm finding while using multi-sliverAppBar, it worlks perfect until we dont use upperScrollPart.

Comment: do you just need header type something on 2nd appBar?

Comment: The first AppBar is used to hold the image almost half of the screen with heading and closing button - which on scroll pins to the top. The second AppBar is used to hold horizontal list of categories.

Comment: can you add 2 images of your ui that you are trying to archive?

Comment: Added 2 images, let me know if I made them clear enough. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use SliverPersistentHeader and SliverAppBar.